# discord.py random messages mentioning the user

Tags: discord.py

py recently and I would like the bot to send random messages mentioning the user but it gives me this error:

**discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'**

Here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def randomroman(ctx, *,member: discord.Member=None):

    mention = member.mention
    variable=[
        f'{mention} ama tanto roman!',
        f'{mention} odia tanto roman!',
        f'{mention} ama roman!',
        f'{mention} odia roman!'
    ]
    await ctx.message.channel.send(random.choice(variable))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it would appear that you have set a default value, therefore you should check if a member has been mentioned before trying to send a message. Here are two different pieces of code that you could use.

```py
@client.command()
async def randomroman(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if not member:
        # We dont have anyone to mention so tell the user
        await ctx.send("You need to mention someone for me to mention!")
        return

    variable=[
        f'{member.mention} ama tanto roman!',
        f'{member.mention} odia tanto roman!',
        f'{member.mention} ama roman!',
        f'{member.mention} odia roman!'
    ]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(variable))
```

You can also simply use `ctx.send()`

Another thing you could do is have it mention the author if they dont call the command to mention anyone, like so

```py
@client.command()
async def randomroman(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    member = member or ctx.author

    variable=[
        f'{member.mention} ama tanto roman!',
        f'{member.mention} odia tanto roman!',
        f'{member.mention} ama roman!',
        f'{member.mention} odia roman!'
    ]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(variable))
```

In this situation, both of these will work. `!randomroman` and `!randomroman @user` will mention a user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much! The second is what I needed ...
I have a problem with `if not member` because on some it does not calculate it for me ... I asked and I still can not solve can you help me in this?

Comment: Care to share where you asked?

Comment: in the end I solved, now I have problems with `if not arg`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865285/discord-py-problems-with-if-not-arg-clear-command